# Hello, I just recently started working with flutter and I have an error when I create a second class, it just doesn't show up in the project itse

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a form consisting of nextformfield and elevatedButton. I want to repeat the same form just below on the screen in the same page. I have never tried to do this and it didn't work out, please help.

Here is my code in which I want to do this:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class gradysu extends StatefulWidget {
  const gradysu({super.key});

  @override
  State<gradysu> createState() => _gradysuState();
}

class _gradysuState extends State<gradysu> {
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var x, y, c, d;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Квадрат'),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 252, 252),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: 800,
            width: 639,
            /* decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/image/fon2.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),*/
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 1000.0,
                    child: Center(
                        child: const Text(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                            'Расчёт площади квадрата S=:'))),
                Row(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: const Text('Введите градусы:',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0))),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isEmpty) return 'Задайте градусы';
                                try {
                                  x = double.parse(value);
                                } catch (h) {
                                  x;
                                  return h.toString();
                                }
                              }))),
                ]),
                const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Text(
                  y == null ? '' : ' $y (рад) ',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        setState(() {
                          if (x is double) y = ((x * pi) / 180);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 235,
                          235), //change background color of button
                      backgroundColor:
                          Colors.brown, //change text color of button
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                      ),
                      elevation: 5.0,
                    ),
                    child: const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text(
                          'Вычислить',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ))),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class gradysu1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const gradysu1({super.key});

  @override
  State<gradysu1> createState() => _gradysu1State();
}

class _gradysu1State extends State<gradysu1> {
  var _formKey1 = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var a, c;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey1,
        child: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
                child: Column(children: [
          Row(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: const Text('Введите градусы:',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0))),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) return 'Задайте градусы';
                          try {
                            a = double.parse(value);
                          } catch (h) {
                            a;
                            return h.toString();
                          }
                        }))),
          ]),
          const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Text(
            a == null ? '' : ' $a (рад) ',
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey1.currentState!.validate()) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (c is double) a = ((c * pi) / 180);
                  });
                }
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                foregroundColor: Color.fromARGB(
                    255, 235, 235, 235), //change background color of button
                backgroundColor: Colors.brown, //change text color of button
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                ),
                elevation: 5.0,
              ),
              child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Text(
                    'Вычислить',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ))),
        ]))));
  }
}
```

[image]

This is what it looks like

[image]

And this is how it should look like

I tried to create another class, but flutter just doesn't see it, I tried to add it to the main code, but then he just didn't count, but threw an exception.

Comment: include another widget as top

Answer (score 0):

Try to create reusable widget or builder method to minimize the snippet/code-dublication.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: gradysu(),
  ));
}

class gradysu extends StatefulWidget {
  const gradysu({super.key});

  @override
  State<gradysu> createState() => _gradysuState();
}

class _gradysuState extends State<gradysu> {
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var x, y, c, d;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Квадрат'),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 252, 252),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: 800,
            width: 639,
            /* decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/image/fon2.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),*/
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    child: Center(
                        child: const Text(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                            'Расчёт площади квадрата S=:'))),
                Row(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: const Text('Введите градусы:',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0))),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) return 'Задайте градусы';
                          try {
                            x = double.parse(value);
                          } catch (h) {
                            x;
                            return h.toString();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
                const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Text(
                  y == null ? '' : ' $y (рад) ',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (x is double) y = ((x * pi) / 180);
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Color.fromARGB(
                        255, 235, 235, 235), //change background color of button
                    backgroundColor: Colors.brown, //change text color of button
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    ),
                    elevation: 5.0,
                  ),
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Text(
                      'Вычислить',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                /// second item , you can create a build method for this
                Row(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: const Text('Введите градусы:',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0))),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) return 'Задайте градусы';
                          try {
                            x = double.parse(value);
                          } catch (h) {
                            x;
                            return h.toString();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
                const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Text(
                  y == null ? '' : ' $y (рад) ',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (x is double) y = ((x * pi) / 180);
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Color.fromARGB(
                        255, 235, 235, 235), //change background color of button
                    backgroundColor: Colors.brown, //change text color of button
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                    ),
                    elevation: 5.0,
                  ),
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Text(
                      'Вычислить',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```